# restrict characters in form field

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I've an HTML field in a form and, using JS and Regex, I must restrict the characters the user can insert in the field. The user of the form can only insert the following characters `( ) * + ^ / X x`, and numbers and spaces (when he digits or pastes a different character nothing is written). Is this possible? I need the Regex, I eventually know how to do with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
[^\(\)\*+\^/Xx0-9 ]
```

Here we are trying to find a pattern which contains none of the allowed characters. If you find it this means that the character entered was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong answer to this.
Usually it is less expensive to check using the bias of the logic for the particular condition.
If it sounds better saying whats *allowed*, then use the allowed (positive) character class.

Allowed class: `[()*+^/Xx0-9 ]`, Checks: `<space>` `(-+` `/-9` `X` `\^` `x`

Not allowed class: `[^()*+^/Xx0-9 ]`, Checks: `\0-\37` `!-'` `,` `\-` `.` `:-W` `Y-\]` `_-w` `y-\377`

Statistically,   if %99 of the data enterred were valid, the 'Allowed' class would do less work in that
not every character or range has to be checked.
Where the 'Not-Allowed' class will have to check every range.

In this particular case, the negative class has many more ranges and characters to check, its borderline
more efficient if most of the data were invalid,

Answer (score 0):

With regard to:

```
[^\(\)\*+\^/Xx0-9 ]
```

None of those characters need to be escaped inside a set (but it is okay to do so).

If you want to restrict as the user types (this uses jquery methods):

```
$('#in1').keyup(function (evt) {
    var content = $('#in1').val();
    $('#in1').val(content.replace(/[^()*+^/Xx0-9]/g, ""));
    return true;
});
```

Where 'in1' is the id of the input.

Comment: This will not restrict input that is coming from a `Paste` using only the mouse.

Comment: @StephenP: how to check for that?

Comment: @3000 - there is an `onpaste` event. Cancelling the event (via returning false or an actual 'cancel' API) prevents the paste from occurring. I have at least one case where I use all of the following events as a place to validate input:
 `onkeyup`, `onchange`, `onpaste`, `onblur`, `onselectionchange`